# How can i set up xdotool to hold down a key so that mouse button 2 is held and releases when the key is released?

Tags: linux, linux-mint, keyboard-shortcuts

I am in linux mint, I would like to hold down the ` key to click and drag using mouse button 2.

I have
`xdotool mousedown 2`
which holds down mouse button 2

and
`xdotool mouseup 2`
which releases mouse button 2

but I can't figure out how to separate them by the release of the ` key.

Any ideas?
Thanks